# Laravel Virtual Host Request Url Not found

Tags: php, laravel, virtualhost

I'm having a problem with my laravel application using VirtualHosts, I can see the home page of laravel but when I try to make a route like advkit.dev/login I get "The requested URL /login was not found on this server." So all my routes aren't working does anyone know what I need to change in my code to make routes work. I also have set debug to true and I only get the debuging console on the home page e.g advkit.dev no where else

route:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

// login.blade.php
Route::get('/login', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1       www.localhost.com
127.0.0.2       advkit.dev
```

httpd-hosts file

```
<VirtualHost advkit.dev>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\advkit\public
    ServerName advkit.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: do you have your mod-rewrites set up properly ? I can't see anything wrong with your code or configuration.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the rewrites what do I do

Comment: sometimes laravel does not work with the default configuration. In their website they have given another rewrite. Try this one. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: I'm using laravel 4.2 and that code didn't work

Answer (score 3):

> You can add the following lines in your .conf file.

```
<Directory /var/www/gloops/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

After save the files and enable rewrite mode by the given command and restart the apache2 service.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the virtualhost setup given in the following answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760330/4561150

```
<Directory "C:/myproject/mysubfolder/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Apache is ignoring your `.htaccess` file. You could fix that, but the better solution is to put the contents of that `.htaccess` file in your virtualhost. Then your virtualhost would look like this:

```php
<VirtualHost advkit.dev>
    DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\advkit\public
    ServerName advkit.dev

    <Directory C:\wamp\www\advkit\public>
        # Ignore the .htaccess file in this directory
        AllowOverride None

        # Rewrite URLs
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                Options -MultiViews
            </IfModule>

            RewriteEngine On

            # Redirect Trailing Slashes
            RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

            # Handle Front Controller
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```