# Laravel 5.1 Route Object not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, frameworks, xampp

Please help me, I'm working on a Laravel using the latest version of xampp & do not know what the cause of my problem is.

This route is working fine:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'aa';
});
```

This route gives an error "Object not found!":

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return 'aaa';
});
```

httpd.vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost test.loc:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public"
   ServerName test.loc
   <Directory "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public">
            #AllowOverride All - when I use this, I get a "Access forbidden!" for all routes
        Require all granted - this works for the main route, other routes give "errors".
</Directory>
```

/public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced exactly the same problem, but finally this worked for me.

```
.....
<Directory "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: AllowOverride All
solved my problem at xampp windows

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your httpd.vhosts file

```
<VirtualHost test.loc:80> 

 ServerName test.loc
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/apps/test.loc/public">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: the result is: Error 500 Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Comment: A server 500 error is a VERY general error. Did you check your PHP error logs?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a slash before the name?
like this:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return 'aaa';
});
```

Comment: yes i tried, the some result: error Object not found!

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: make sure your rewrite module is activated and your `.htaccess` is being loaded. also check the permissions of `/public` folder