# Post request not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and am trying to do a simple `post` request but it is not working. It is says `object not found` after redirecting to `/o2`. Could someone shed some light on it? I am using `CSRF Token` too but things aren't working. Using v5.2 of Laravel.

```
 Route::get('/o1', function(){
   echo '<form method="post" action="/o2"><input name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '" type="hidden"><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>';
});

Route::post('/o2', function(){
   echo "It works";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a post route in your browser to print the form. This is not going to work. You need to create a get route to print the form and then set the action to the post route. Try something like this:

```
Route::get('/o1', function(){
   echo '<form method="post" action="/o2"><input name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '" type="hidden"><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>';
});

Route::post('/o2', function(Request $request) {
   echo $request->all();
});
```

Comment: I have altered the question after I realized the problem, plz take a look. It is still not working.

Comment: Are you using apache?

Comment: I am using Xampp.

Comment: This is probably a problem with virtual hosts / htaccess. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129612/xampp-localhost-returns-object-not-found-after-installing-laravel

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814576/laravel-5-1-route-object-not-found

Comment: Could you plz tell me what the problem might be? Also where is htaccess/virtual hosts located?

Comment: I am no able to help on this because I don't use Xampp, but I would search for this subject. The code is correct, the problem now is configuration. Search for "Object not found" and "Laravel route xampp" and you should get something.

Comment: Thanks, plz do look for the solution and I am gonna look for it too. I have spent a day trying to figure out a way to make it work but it still ain't working.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this route when you get the MethodNotAllowedHttpException ?

This post request should be called by the actual form you are creating.
And should generally not return the actual form but persist the data and then redirect the user to the page to show the result.

So in general you would have a get and a post:

```
Route::get('/o1', function(){
   echo '<form method="post" action="/o2"><input name="_token" value="' . csrf_token() . '" type="hidden"><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>';
});

Route::post('/o1', function(){
   // persist your form here
});
```

I strongly recommend using a controller for this.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers

Comment: I have made changes in the question above, it is still not working, plz check above.